# How to sent page URL when clicking on leaflet marker?

Tags: javascript, php, html, leaflet

I want to be able to send the page URL and open a page when clicking on a leaflet marker.

If you believe there are better alternatives to submit the LINK please provided it below and will be more than happy to try it.

I need help getting the URL sent on the FORM

page_template_mobile.php

```
<head>
<script>

// Variable containing page URL
var siteURL = location.href;

// When click on blue marker, send URL and go to page
function onClick(e) {
    document.myform.submit();
}

//Start location marker
const marker = L.marker([0, 0]).on('click', onClick).addTo(map).bindTooltip("Click here to upload a picture",
    {
        permanent: true,
        direction: 'right'
    }
);

</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="myform" action="/uas_tools/visualization_generator/V2/Resources/PHP/upload_picture.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" id="custId" name="custId" value=<script> siteURL </script>>
    <a href="javascript: submitform()">Search</a>
</form>
</body>
```

upload_picture.php

```
<?php
$page_url = $_POST['custId'];

_log('page_url: ' .$page_url);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved

```
// Variable containing page URL
var siteURL = location.href;
// URL is saved on custId 
document.getElementById("custId").value = siteURL;

<form name="myform" action="/uas_tools/visualization_generator/V2/Resources/PHP/upload_picture.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" id="custId" name="custId">
    <a href="javascript: submitform()"></a>
</form>
```